# TCM User Access. 401 Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1, content-manager, user-management

This is pertaining to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1. We are not using LDAP, instead Active Directory.

The userids are appearing in the Trustees table as well as correct privileges in the TCM Admin as System Admin.

However we are still getting this error below:

Server Error

401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

[image: Browser Error]

Any thoughts on why this error would be occurring?

We can also log into our sandbox with our AD credentials on a Windows 2008 vm, but we cannot login with our AD credentials on a Windows 2012 vm..

Here is a picture of the Tridion Logs:

[image: Event Viewer Logs]

[image: Tridion Detail XML]

[image: Tridion General Details Error]

Comment: Anything in the event log? What browser are u using? Does it prompt you for username? Do you enter domain as well?

Comment: I have tried both with domain\username and strictly username. I have tried all browsers, IE specifically I can see the Server Error, the others just spin and try to load..checking the event log now

Comment: @user978511 - Do these pictures help at all? Or do you need system or application event logs?

Comment: It has something to do with IIS, check IIS logs, also check Tridion application pool settings. Did you change any web.configs, or anything in the IIS? It looks to me that it's either web.config or IIS misconfiguration, IIS security issue, or some of the required windows components was not installed.

Comment: Can you please check if the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE is added in Impersonation Users

Comment: @PrasoonSrivastava - Yes, I have verified that NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE is added the same way as in our sandbox environment. I have also reviewed multiple logs and settings that seem to match up with our sandbox environment as well. The only difference between our sandbox and DTCM box is Sand is using Windows 2008 VM and this Dev install is Windows 2012 VM. Also, I am not sure if has anything to do with Active Directory or permissions internally..

Comment: @user978511 - I am reviewing all windows components installed and config files, and IIS setting now. I will let you know if I see anything.

Comment: @user978511 I was added as a remote user to the box, but I cannot RDP into it. I think it may have something to do with Active Directory and permissions to this vm or group in AD I am set up in. I get this error: "An authentication error has occurred. The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted"

Comment: Went into the vm to drive: tridion >> Properties >> Security and updated these permissions: NETWORK SERVICE: Modify, Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, Read, Write

IIS_IUSRS: Modify, Read & Execute, List Folder Contents, Read, Write

Comment: Start -> Run -> RSoP.msc and reviewed results for Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment and Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Restricted Groups for any errors flagged with a red X. And 'Access this computer from Network' had an error. Computer Setting Administrators_Authenticated Users.

"The policy xyz_Server2012_MSB_v1.2 resulted in the following error No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. For more info, see %windir%\security\logs\winlogon.log on the target machine."

Comment: I think your machine just fell out of windows domain, then indeed you can't login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate everyone's input on this error. The only setting that needed to be changed was the User Right Assignment setting by adding Authenticated Users. I have updated the test GPO to only include this setting and it appears to be working as expected.